# MongoDB: How can I insert a document which has a value that should be evaluated via querying?

Tags: mongodb

Like this:

I have a document,

```
{ "_id": "java", "belongs":"Oracle"}
```

and I want to insert a new document which belongs to the same place as java.

```
{ "_id":"mysql", "belongs":db.collection.find({_id:"oracle"}, {"_id":0, "belongs":1})}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is to remember that `find()` returns a cursor, not a document.  The other important detail is that you should be querying for the document with the "java" `_id`, not "oracle".  You can then use the `belongs` field of that document in your `insert()`.  So, what you want to be doing is this:

```
db.collection.insert({ 
   _id: "mysql", 
   belongs: db.collection.findOne({_id: "java"}).belongs
})
```

This makes use of the `findOne` method, which returns the first *document* that matches the query. Since in MongoDB `_id` serves as the primary key for your collection, there should only be one such document anyway.

Comment: Actually, the `_id` was assigned "oracle" at first and I changed it later to avoid confusion.But I forgot to change the query accordingly. By the way, thank you for correcting my mistakes.